# Java regex: Problem with double quotes and word boundary

Tags: java, regex, word-boundary

I have a problem with matching text that ends with double quotes and word boudary.

Here is an example.

I need to match: 
`TEST "A"` in some text.

If I have the string
`aaa TEST "A" aaa` it should match.

`aaa TEST "A\"\n` should also match

If I have the string
`aaa TEST "A"aaa` it should not match.

So I've defined my regular expression like this:

```
.*\bTEST "A"\b.*
```

The problem is that

```
Pattern.matches(".*\\bTEST \"A\"\\b.*", "aaa TEST \"A\" aaa")
```

return false

I don't understand why.
Which change should I do the the regex so that is matches ?

Comment: Replace the second `\b` with `\B`, see https://regex101.com/r/Y6niX0/1

Answer (score -1):

A simpler way to do this would be to remove the word boundary and test for `TEST "A"` and a [`\s`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp) (space/newline) afterwards. Try this regex: `TEST "A"\s`. It works well on all the cases you provided:

```js
const regex = /TEST "A"\s/;

console.log(regex.test(`aaa TEST "A" aaa`));
//=> true

console.log(regex.test(`aaa TEST "A"\n`));
//=> true

console.log(regex.test(`aaa TEST "A"aaa`));
//=> false
```

(The snippet above is in JavaScript, but the regex would work in Java the same way)

---

Edit: As @slartidan suggested below, if the regex should match `aaa TEST "A"` as well, you should use this regex instead: `TEST "A"(\s|$)`:

```js
const regex = /TEST "A"(\s|$)/;

console.log(regex.test(`aaa TEST "A"`));
//=> true
```

Comment: If the end of the string (`$`) should also be valid after the `"`, then I suggest: `/TEST "A"(\s|$)/`.